b-movie with gang of 80's or 90's
Is NOT Judgement night with Cuba Gooding Junior
Recorded in USA,in the years between 87-94
Some young "good boys" lost in "not good" neighbor
were chased by a gang of thugs.
They fought against the thugs and "win".
A black boy from neighbor help them.
I remind some scenes
scene number one:
A girl is bound somewhere,and one of the thugs want to rape her using a knife,but the black boy magical appear and kill the thug(or only beat him..)
scene number two:
The gang is in difficult ,and they call the "man of death",a strange "skinhead" with strange black signs on face(like Commando)
Scene number three: 
The "man of death" bound one of the boy and shoot him with a shotgun,
the black boy said "man of death" kill also his mother(not mother of black boy!).
Anyone know this?
GENRE: ACTION,similar to Judgment Night,Warriors,etc..

COUNTRY: USA 

RELEASED ON: VHS,TV

YEAR: 1987-1995


Any other movies you've ruled out?

Found. The movie was "Chains"
The "dead man" with "commando" paint on face.

